# How can I make a terminal with 3 tabs appear after startup?

Tags: command-line, xubuntu, login, xfce4-terminal

- Xubuntu 13.10

I would like to have `xfce4-terminal` appear automatically after logging in. I would like to have this instance of the terminal have 3 tabs, the first one being title `htop`, the second one titled `man` and the last one titled `Stuff`.

Example:

[image]

Is that possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Run `xfce4-session-settings` → Application Autostart → Add
2. Put a name and a description (optional), then add this command:

   ```
   xfce4-terminal -T htop -e htop --tab -T man --tab -T Stuff
   ```

   or with `sudo htop` so it just wait for your password:

   ```
   xfce4-terminal -T htop -e "sudo htop" --tab -T man --tab -T Stuff
   ```

   - `--tab` create new tab
   - `-T` Title
   - `-e` execute command

References:

- [XFCE Frequently asked questions: Session Manager](https://wiki.xfce.org/faq#session_manager), `xfce4-autostart-editor` was integrated to `xfce4-session-settings` See [bug#911688 Obsolete xfce4-autostart-editor manpage](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-session/+bug/911688)
- `man xfce4-terminal`

Comment: Excellent answer! Referenced here: https://superuser.com/questions/471517/how-can-i-save-my-multiple-tabs-session-in-an-xfce4-terminal/1308157#1308157